# issue with table border while using itextsharp in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, itext

i need to build a pdf using itextsharp. curently my issue is i cannot make the table border width to 0px. i dont want the table or cell border..
my code is

```
Document Doc = new Document();
    //PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath
    //(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\TTS_Bill.pdf", FileMode.Create));

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/DMSDOC/DMS_doc.pdf"), FileMode.Create));

    Doc.Open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;

    table.TotalWidth = 400f;

    table.LockedWidth = true;

    iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("~/img/val verde hospital.png");
    logo.ScaleAbsolute(40, 40);

    PdfPCell image_header = new PdfPCell(logo);
    image_header.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    table.AddCell(image_header)
```

how can it be solved or is there any mistake in my code...

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF illustrating the problem and allowing to investigate the origins of the border.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer was almost correct.

Setting the `DefaultCell` is fine, but it only works if you use `AddCell()` with a `string` value or a `Phrase` object. If you create your own `PdfPCell`, you need something like this:

```
image_header.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these two.

```
table.borderwidth= 0;
```

OR

```
table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0 
table.DefaultCell.Border = iText.Rectangle.NO_BORDER
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if this works. As I don't have itext sharp installed now, I can't test this.